# Problema codificación Java linux

Tags: php, java

Tengo una aplicación hecha en netbeans en windows10 y funciona correctamente, una vez compilada y obtenido el jar, uso el mismo jar para ubuntu y me aparecen problemas de codificación, intente compilarla con el netbeans en ubuntu y los problemas siguen.
La aplicación en java manda una peticion post a un script actualizar.php que se encarga de actualizar la base de datos. En windows funciona correctamente pero en ubuntu cuando intento actualizar el comentario con una ñ o un caracter con tilde me aparecen caracteres  raros por ejemplo si pongo un comentario "café mañana "  en la base de datos se inserta "cafÃ© maÃ±ana"

La función Java encargada de mandar la petición es la siguiente:

```
private static final String POST_URLur = "http://ruta/alScript/actualizar.php";
private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static void updaterestantePOST(String fecha, String comentario) throws IOException {
        
        
        POST_PARAMSur="fecha="+fecha+"&comentario="+comentario;
        URL obj = new URL(POST_URLur);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        
        // For POST only - START
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        
              
        os.write(POST_PARAMSur.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END
        int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);
    
    }
```

Y el script php actualizar.php sería el siguiente:

```
<?php
    include 'conexion.php';

    
    $comentario1=$_POST["comentario"];
    $fecha=$_POST["fecha"];
    
    $db=mysqli_connect("$hostname","$username","$password","$database");
    $comentario2=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$comentario1);
    $comentario=utf8_encode($comentario2);
    mysqli_query($db,"set names 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($db,"update tabla set comentarios='$comentario'where fecha='$fecha'");
  ?>
```

Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?? versión netbeans8.2  - versión ubuntu 18.04 - versión jdk 1.8.0 - codificación del proyecto netbeans: UTF-8

Probé a agregar :

```
os.write(POST_PARAMSur.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Pero no funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Probando he encontrado la solución...
modificando la linea:

```
os.write(POST_PARAMSur.getBytes(Charset.forName("windows-1252")));
```

Pero no entiendo el por qué?
Resulta que codificando en windows-1252 funciona...